# ember-cli-clipboard dynamic clipboardTarget

Tags: javascript, ember.js, clipboard.js

I’m using the [ember-cli-clipboard](https://github.com/jkusa/ember-cli-clipboard) wrapper to create a set of buttons within an `{{#each}}...{{/each}}` loop that should copy a small text to the clipboard if you click it. Each element has its own text and its own button. Unfortunately I can not set the `clipboardTarget` with a dynamic ID, so the buttons will all copy only from the first element instead of copying from each single element.

The component looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each element as |item|}}

        {{#copy-button clipboardTarget=".name" success=(action 'copiedCharacter')}}
            <span class="name">{{item.text}}</span>
        {{/copy-button}}

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Instead of the `clipboardTarget=".name"` I would need something like a  `{{uniqueID}}`:

```
<ul>
    {{#each element as |item|}}

        {{#copy-button clipboardTarget="{{uniqueID}}" success=(action 'copiedCharacter')}}
            <span id="{{uniqueID}}">{{item.text}}</span>
        {{/copy-button}}

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Creating the ID is not the problem, but passing it inside the `{{#copy-button ...}}` does not work... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it direclty like this `clipboardTarget=uniqueID`

```
        {{#copy-button clipboardTarget=uniqueID success=(action 'copiedCharacter')}}
            <span id={{uniqueID}}>{{item.text}}</span>
        {{/copy-button}}
```

Comment: how nice ...  i thought it is a syntax thing.. I just needed to add a ´#´ for an id element to get it work as `clipboardTarget `. I made something like `clipboardTargeWithHash`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You are welcome...just a hint there is [concat helper](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat) which may be useful for simple concatenation.